# How to get auto-increment after executing SQLQuery.executeUpdate() insert statement

Tags: sql, hibernate, auto-increment

Is it possible to retrieve autoinc field after I execute my insert:

```
String queryString = "insert into " + String.format("table%04d", id) +
                "(sectionid, topicid, dc) values (" + entry.getSectionId() +
            ", " + entry.getTopicId() + ", " + entry.getDc() + ")";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
query.executeUpdate();
```

The table has four fields

```
eid - autoinc
sectionid - int
topicid - int
dc - int
```

Please help me

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621369/sql-insert-and-catch-the-id-auto-increment-value/1452145#1452145

Comment: What if I don't know what the database is going to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are bypassing much of Hibernate's database agnostic benefits, by using SQL queries instead of HQL. If you absolutely cannot use HQL, you will have to implement your own database specfic implementations. To do that, you first need to get the JDBC driver class from Hibernate:

[How to get database metadata from entity manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607196/how-to-get-database-metadata-from-entity-manager)

Once you have you driver class, you can do a database specific query based on that class. Since you can't modify the driver class to implement an interface with a specific get autoinc query, I recommend Nico's suggestion in the following link:

[switch instanceof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579309/switch-instanceof)

Once you implement a switch statement on the driver class, you can choose whether to implement a MYSQL, MSSQL, or other autoinc query.