# Visualizing an embedded H2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, database-schema, h2, auto-generate

I'm trying to configure and use a H2 embedded DB with Spring Boot. I'm using the code provided in [the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.html):

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabase db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
    .generateUniqueName(true)
    .setType(H2)
    .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
    .ignoreFailedDrops(true)
    // .addScript("schema.sql") Omit, auto-generate
    .build();
}
```

The application works fine, I can create and retrieve data, but I would like to visually see it. I've installed the [H2 Console Application](http://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html), but I'm not sure how to connect to the in-memory instance. I go to http://localhost:8082 and then, under JDBC URL I input when I get from the [connection's metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607196/how-to-get-database-metadata-from-entity-manager) (I've tried with auto-generated and manually specified names), but the H2 Console Application seems to be connected to an empty schema. My tables don't appear there, only the information schema, and I can't `SELECT` from my tables either, they just don't exist here.

What's going on, what DB am I connecting to? How can I connect to my embedded DB?

Comment: try with this http://localhost:8082/h2-console and use this as the jdbl url to connect  jdbc:h2:mem:testdb

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see your tables on h2 console in your application, you don't need to install "Console Application". You just need to **enable** to see visually and also set your datasource url in `application.properties` . It seems like that:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:nprensen;(or if you have already a ds you should write that url)
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/console  // this is the path for h2 console:localhost:8080/console
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Spring is just ignoring those. The console is not accessible and the DB's URL is the same as before.

Comment: @nprensen Can you share your error? The console can be accessible in normal situation.Maybe you did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following dependency you can serve http requests. In that way, you can send a http request to access h2 console from your browser.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30467639)